# Show camera inputs at different axes - MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab, webcam

I have 3 web cameras and 3 axes in MATLAB's GUI. How can I  place webcaminput1 to axes1, webcaminput2 to axes2 and webcaminput3 to axes3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you give more details on how you get input from webcam and display it on the screen.

I assume you are using Image Acquisition Toolbox. The usual code to display webcam input is

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo');
preview(vid)
```

[PREVIEW](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/imaq/preview.html) also can accept image object handle as a second parameter. So you can create image object first and use its axis for preview:

```
vid1 = videoinput('winvideo',1); % create video input object from the 1st source
vid2 = videoinput('winvideo',2); % create video input object from the 2nd source
subplot(211)
h1 = image; % create image object
axis ij % flip the image
preview(vid1,h1) % display 1st webcam preview
subplot(212) % same for the 2nd camera
h2 = image;
axis ij
preview(vid2,h2)
```

I don't have multiple webcams, so I didn't test this code, but I hope it will work for multiple cameras.